# Is it possible to map int(enum) to type

Tags: c++, dictionary

lets say I have this simplified example:
I have some code that does serialization and deserialization of a class...
first byte is enum that encodes class type(they all inherit from same base)..
eg.

```
    Color* c;
    auto classType == read_byte(buffer);
    switch (classType)
    case eBlue:
    {
       c = new Blue(buffer);
    }
    case eGray:
    {
       c = new Gray(buffer)
    }

//...
```

is there any way to have a map from enum to **type** so I can replace switch

```
c = new enum2Type(buffer);
```

edit ofc I would never use raw ptr IRL.:)

Comment: `std::map<TheEnumType, std::function<Color*(TheBufferType)>`?

Comment: Google for "virtual constructor" for some ideas.

Comment: Also look at the "Related" links, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968691/c-create-object-of-certain-type-mapped-to-an-enum and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995378/c-template-for-mapping-struct-type-to-enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
T* makeColor(Buffer const& buffer)
{
    return new T(buffer);
}

...

std::map<ColerEnum, Color* (*)(Buffer const&)> m;
m[grayEnum] = makeColor<Gray>;

...

Color* c = m[typeByte](buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your switch case by a map or array of functors with a buffer parameter, returning a (smart) pointer to `Color`:

```
enum EnumType { blueEnum, grayEnum };
struct Buffer { .... };
struct Color { .... };

template <typename T>
Color* make_stuff(const Buffer& b) { return new T(b); }
```

then

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
...

// if you are sure enum values start at 0 and increase withoug jumps, 
// you could use a plain array
std::map<EnumType, std::function<Color*(const Buffer&)>> m;

m[grayEnum] = make_stuff<Gray>;
m[blueEnum] = make_stuff<Blue>;

Color* c = m.at(classType);
```

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You can save some of the duplication by using a function template.