# Is it possible to use boost fusion map in reverse, aka key is 567, value is type ?

Tags: c++, boost, visitor-pattern, boost-fusion

I would like to have 
value to type map, and from what I see boost fusion uses map that uses pair where type is always the first memeber(so it is key in a map)?

```
map_type m(
    fusion::make_pair<int>('X')
  , fusion::make_pair<double>("Men"));
```

Is it possible to make value(for example 'X' in example above) key and type value?
If not can I at least do filter based on value(this is slow so It would be nice to know if I can sort fusion vector based on second param and use binary_search on that(again with custom comparator that looks at value, not key).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not in `boost::fusion`, but the trick where you take an list of runtime values and call a functor with a type depending on which matches exists.   I call it magic switch.

You need to enumerate the types at compile time, then associate the runtime type with the offset into said list. `tuple` already maps indexes to types for you.

You cannot *return* the type, but instead you can call a passed in template functo with the type.

However, before going down this path, you should have a concrete goal in mind, and see if; there are less convoluted ways to solve it.

Comment: actually motivation was the magic switch... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691214/is-it-possible-to-map-intenum-to-type recently I stumbled upon fusion and I was wondering is fusion maybe the magic I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Normaly this will not work, because there is not realy a way to represent a type at runtime with same semantics known from compile time, for example there are no virtual constructors (look at Moder C++ Design page 200, paragraph 8.2). But fusion supports `for_each` which *iterates* at compile time over the sequence and calls a *runtime function object*. Now this function object can be a generic filter forwarding a call to another generic function object if its generic predicate returns true.

Now her is the code:

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace boost::fusion;


template<class Pred,class Fun>
 struct filter {
    Pred pred_;
    Fun& fun_;

    filter(Pred p, Fun& f)
        : pred_(p)
        , fun_(f)
    {}

    template<class Pair>
    void operator()(Pair& pair) const {
        if (pred_(pair.second))
            fun_(pair);
    }
 };

 template<class Pred,class Fun>
 filter<Pred,Fun> make_filter(Pred p, Fun& f) {
    return filter<Pred,Fun>(p, f);
 }

 typedef map 
    < pair<int, char>
    , pair<double, std::string>
 > map_type;

 struct fun {
    template<class First,class Second>
    void operator()(pair<First,Second>& t) const {
        std::cout 
            << typeid(First).name() << std::endl
            << typeid(Second).name() << ":" << t.second << std::endl;
    }
 };

 struct mypred {
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const&) const {
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()(char c) const {
        return c=='X';
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    map_type m(
        make_pair<int>('X'), 
        make_pair<double>("Men")
    );

    for_each(m, make_filter(mypred(),fun()));

    return 0;
}
```

The filter class stores a predicate and a function object. If the predicate returns true on `pair.second` In your case `'X'` it calls the function object. `make_filter` is a little helper to create a filter. Now there are two piece lof code left: my very special predicate `mypred`, which only accept `char` (you have to deal with overloading for more general implementations) and my function object `fun` which outputs type information and the value. In main `for_each` is called with a `filter`. Please note: the  filter is designed to take the function object by reference so it can transport arguments and result. At the end this is a variation of [ad hoc visitation](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813). If you concern about speed, you should know that allmost everything can be inlined. In this particular example only chars are compared, for all other types the result is `false` and no function is called. Of course there is much room for improvement but I have no time to do it now. There may be better ways to implement this but this was my first program with boost.fusion:-).